# How to config ~/.ssh/config when ProxyCommand doesn't work but ssh -tt does

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunneling, proxy

I need ssh host aa , then ssh host bb .
But it is unconvenient, I want to make a config ssh to host bb directly .

I have test all methods and found

```
# Working
ssh -tt root@aa ssh -tt root@bb

# Not work
ssh -J root@aa root@bb
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p root@aa ssh" root@bb
ssh -t -o ProxyCommand='ssh root@aa nc bb 22' root@bb
```

I don't know how to write a config use ssh -tt , all document only talk about ProxyCommand .

Comment: When you say "not work", what do you mean? What happens when you run one of those commands? What error messages do you get?

Comment: @Kenster when you say ssh to xxx , only two case: can login/ can't login , `not work` means which is obvious as my opinion, and I already gave the answer to myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my purposed routine is :
Local -- local rsa --> Proxy -- proxy rsa --> Target

But ssh only allow:
Local -- local rsa --> Proxy -- local rsa --> Target

So, the solution is add local rsa pub_key to Target:

```
ssh root@aa
ssh root@bb
echo 'your_rsa.pub file content' >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

then `ProxyCommand` works .